# How to maintain the data in fragments Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one Activity having 5 buttons: button1, button2, button3, button4, button5.

- button1 clicks----open fragment1
- button2 clicks----openf ragment2
- button3 clicks----open fragment3
- button4 clicks----open fragment4
- button5 clicks----open fragment5

In fragment1 I am downloading data and displaying in a customized listview. In fragment2 I am downloading data and displaying in edittexts, textviews..etc.
But if I click the button1 again data is downloading again. I want to show the same view where the user comes back from fragment1 to fragment2 by clicking buttons.
How can I reach this logic? Please help me in this. If you want any information I will provide. 
Thank you in advance!

EDIT : I need google chrome tab functionality in android fragments.here tabs are fragments.if you open one website in google search and open onother page in anothe tab.if you can navigate to first tab you can see the opened one only.in my case i am starting from the scratch of the fragment.how to reach chrome tab functionality in android fragments.

Comment: can you post a screen-shot  of what u r trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to go around it. whatever data you have download you can store it either temporarily or permanently. if you want to store it temporarily you can:

- use an `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` object to store it.

or permanently using either

- `SQLiteDatabase` or
- `SharedPrefrences`

depending on the data type.

Now whenever you open your fragment you can **check if the data already exists** if not you hit the Service and get the data otherwise you can read directly from the source you have chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architecture on this app.

This means create a class to store this data. Use the [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern when designing the class. First time the user press Button 1, upon creation of the fragment, call a method from the Model class to check if the data is downloaded or not. If it's not downloaded then  fetch it, store it in the class and display it. If data is downloaded then use an method from the Model class to get the data and display it.

If you have small a amount of data to display you can use [bundles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) or [intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to store it.

UPDATE:
Below is a simple example of a singleton class that can be used to store your data and find out if your class contains initialized data or not. In my example I used as data an int value but you are free to use whatever type you want, even a class.

```
public class SingletonExample {
    private static SingletonExample mSingleton = null;
    private int mMyData;
    private boolean mDataInitialized;
    private SingletonExample() {
        mDataInitialized = false;
        }
    public static SingletonExample getInstance() {
            if (mSingleton == null) {
                        mSingleton = new SingletonExample();
                }
            }
            return mSingleton;
    }

    public boolean isDataInitialized() {
        return mDataInitialized;
    }

    public void setMyData(int myData) {
        mMyData = myData;
        mDataInitialized = true;
    }

    public int getMyData() {
        return mMyData;
    }
}
```

The singleton call you call like this:

```
SingletonExample mDataBank = SingletonExample.getInstance( );
mDataBank.setMyData(0);
```

Comment: I edited my answer and included an example of singleton.